# Overriding Initializers in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization, overriding

I'm working on an app where you can put pins on a map and see Flickr images associated with this location.

The app is almost working but I've got a problem with initializers in some classes. A particular example is the following:

```
override init() {
    session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    super.init()
}

convenience init(delegate:HTTPClientProtocol) {
    self.init()
    self.delegate = delegate
}
```

Could somebody please help me figure out what's wrong with this code? On the first line, the error message says

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its
>   superclass

and on the line with `self.init()` the error is

> Value of type '*->*' has no member 'init'

Comment: What base class are you inheriting from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inheriting from `NSObject`, your `override init` works since you're overriding the base initializer for `NSObject`:

```
protocol HTTPClientProtocol { }

class NSObj: NSObject {

    var session: NSURLSession!
    var delegate: HTTPClientProtocol?

    override init() {
        session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(delegate:HTTPClientProtocol) {
        self.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

If your class is a base class that does not inherit from any other class, your `override init` won't work since you don't have a base class initializer to override.  Just create an initializer and a convenience init which invokes the designated initializer you just created:

```
protocol HTTPClientProtocol { }

class Obj {

    var session: NSURLSession!
    var delegate: HTTPClientProtocol?

    init() {
        session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    }

    convenience init(delegate:HTTPClientProtocol) {
        self.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```